# Shipping a React application as a singular JS file

Tags: reactjs, build, create-react-app

I have an application created with create-react-app which needs to be shipped as a singular .js file, complete with its components and CSS style sheets. How can it be done? Without ejecting, if possible. The standard **npm run build** command only provides source code split into chunks.

Tried solving this issue with with **react-rewire-app**, but the build failed to complete.
My config-override.js is as follows:

```
const path = require('path');
module.exports = function override(config, env) {
    config.entry = {
          'my-app': './src/index.js'
    }
    config.module.output =  {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, '../target/classes/static/'),
        filename: '[name].js',
        publicPath: '/'
    }
    return config
}
``
```

Answer (score 1):

You're looking to make a widget or a library, likely, not an application, so CRA is the wrong tool. CRA is a tool for applications, where you definitely don't want everything bundled into a single file like you're asking for, as that would be very poor user experience.

For library/widget bundlers, I'd take a look at something like Microbundle: https://github.com/developit/microbundle. Should be very little config.

That being said, you cannot include CSS style sheets in JS. You can't even import them into JS. You need to ship them along with your JS and let your user handle importing it through HTML or what have you.